# How to remove duplication in request validation?

Tags: clojure

I have a compojure app with a set of routes and handlers.

```
(defroutes app-routes
  (GET "/stuff/:id" [:as request] (stuff/get-stuff request))
  (POST "/stuff/" [:as request] (stuff/create-stuff request))
```

Each handler validates its input, like so

```
(defn create-stuff
  [request]
  (my-validation/validate-request
    request
    my-validation/create-stuff-validator
    stuff-ok-fn))
```

The validation code is based on Metis, and looks like this:

```
(metis/defvalidator :create-stuff-validator
  [:db :presence])

(defn validate-request
  [request request-validator ok-function]
  (let [validation-result (request-validator request)]
    (if (empty? validation-result)
      (ok-function request)
      (bad-request validation-result))))
```

My problem is that code in create-stuff is duplicated across each of the route handlers; i.e the get-stuff function looks like the create-stuff handler. The only thing that differs is their validator function and their the-validation-went-well-function.

How can I abstract this duplication in a idiomatic Clojure manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a functional language, I suggest passing the functions that differentiate the handlers into a generic handler function.

```
;;; in core.clj
(defroutes app-routes
  (GET "/stuff/:id" [:as request]
       (handlers/handle
        my-validation/get-stuff-validator
        stuff/get-stuff-ok-fn
        request))
  (POST "/stuff/" [:as request]
        (handlers/handle
         my-validation/create-stuff-validator
         stuff/create-stuff-ok-fn
         request)))

;;; in handlers.clj

(defn handle
  [validator action request]
  (let [validation-result (validator request)]
    (if (empty? validation-result)
      (action request)
      (bad-request validation-result))))
```

Stylistically, I suggest that the code would be easier to read if you avoid [the smurf naming convention](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/new-programming-jargon.html). The namespace tells us if you are validating, or that "stuff" is what you are operating on, you don't need to include it in the name of the function. Also, the fact that you are passing an argument that should be callable is sufficient, you don't need to put fn in the name of the function, the fact that it is passed as the ok branch tells us it is the thing to do when things go ok.

```
;;; in core.clj
(defroutes app-routes
  (GET "/stuff/:id" [:as request]
       (handlers/handle
        my-validation/get-stuff
        stuff/get
        request))
  (POST "/stuff/" [:as request]
        (handlers/handle
         my-validation/create-stuff
         stuff/create
         request)))

;;; in handlers.clj

(defn handle
  [validator ok request]
  (let [errors (validator request)]
    (if (empty? errors)
      (ok request)
      (bad-request errors))))
```

if you can reduce verbosity without losing clarity, you improve correctness, because errors hide in verbosity.